# I'm trying to go through an html page line by line in perl, but it just looks at the entire file as one line. How do I fix this?

Tags: perl

So I've defined a url in my code and then I assign it to content, so the entire html file should be stored in `$content`. When I read from STDIN, it automatically goes line-by-line, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. The `$end == 1` part is just to say when the while loop should stop. I'm new to Perl so it's probably just a little syntax thing but I've tried playing around with using a double equal sign or moving the `$line = $content` part inside the loop, but I still can't fix it. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
my $content = get $url;
while(my $line = $content && $end == 1) {
    #code to edit line
}
```

Comment: You assign `$line` the value of a scalar. That will only be one value, unless you change that scalar inside the loop. And you seem to change the scalar outside the loop.

Comment: What is `get`?  How do you know the HTML stream contains newlines?  Does `get` know to split the stream into lines in array context?

Comment: when I view the source code in the browser it splits it up into lines, so I assumed it would carry over to perl

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
my @content = get $url;
foreach my $line (@content) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the server returns a stream containing newlines, and that `get` knows to split into lines in array context.  I don't think the OP has provided enough information yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($content =~ /\G(.*\n|.+\z)/g) {
   my $line = $1;
   ...
}
```

---

As for `$end`, your variable is badly named or your logic is inverted. Anyway, such a construct is totally unnecessary; just use [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html).